# Redis -- how does it improve performance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, memcached

i'm relatively new to the world of web-development and have only recently learned memory hierarchies in computer systems. I recently came across Redis and am itching to try it out in a small web-app. But before I do, I was wondering how is Redis going to improve performance? From what i've read so far, it seems that Redis is an "in-memory" data store, so does that mean that whenever a user requests a data from the server, instead of fetching from the database (given that the Redis data store is already populated with the needed data) the request can be fulfilled by accessing the data directly from the server's memory? To be specific, say if i have a web-app which back-end server is hosted on AWS, and the database is stored on MLAB, then whenever a user requests a data, instead of querying to the server which redirects the request to MLAB, it can now directly fetch the data from the server without going to MLAB ? Also, by in-memory, does that mean that the data is stored in the RAM on my AWS server?

Finally, how is this different from a cache?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Redis is used as a cache, the difference with most of the traditional cache is that you have other nice structures like hashes, sets, lists, TTL on keys, hyperlologs and so on, not only pair key:value.

You are right what you define about Redis, is but take into account that if you want to move your data from MLAB database to Redis you have to design some process to keep Redis update in each update that happens in your database. So every query from your application will use Redis to get data but apart from that you will need a process to keep update Redis with changes on your database, so if you use your application to update the database (and there are no other external parts which update your DB), every time you get an update from your web-app you have to update the DB and also Redis or having a command/script which detect every time an updated happened in the DB and update Redis properly.

AWS also provides Redis services, like ElasticCache https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/?nc1=h_ls so basically the AWS ECS instance where you have your application doesn't use the RAM but this ElasticCache service which can live on another physical machine.

Finally, Redis store on memory the data though, it uses a dump file to save partial data in case of crashes and it also offers a persistence mode